# I need some help in GAP System

Tags: finite-groups, gap

I am new to GAP system. I would like to find all groups of order $p^n$ with 
$\text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Aut}(G/\Phi(G))$ surjective.

$$\text{Aut}(G/Φ(G))=\text{GL}(L,p) \text{ and } G/Φ(G)= C^L× ......× C^L \text{ ($p$-times)}.$$

---

I'm  trying to do that in GAP but i don't know how to find all groups. or is that true or not? As example the group is SmallGroup(n,p)

```
G:= SmallGroup(n,p);
StructureDescription(G);
A:= AutomorphismGroupPGroup(G);
l:= RankPGroup(G);
p:= PrimePGroup(G);

if Size(A) = Size(GL(n,l))*p^(l*(n-l)) then
    return true;




TestCondition := function( G, d, p )
    local A;

A := AutomorphismGroupPGroup(Factor(G, FrattiniSubgroup(G)));
if IsomorphismGroups(A, GL(d,p)) <> fail then
    return true;
else
    return false;
fi;
end;

for n in [1..100] do
    if IsPrimePowerInt(n) then
        for m in [1..NumberSmallGroups(n)] do
            if TestCondition(SmallGroup(n,m)) = true then
                # ...
            fi;
        od;
    fi;
od;
```

Comment: if you're interested how to organise a search in the Small Groups Library, see https://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups/ - hope that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition test is quite expensive in testing for abstract isomorphism. It will be much cheaper to induce the matrix action on a basis of $G/\Phi(G)$ and check that the resulting group indeed is thew full GL. GAP code for this is:

```
TestCondition:=function(G)
local p,A,phi,pcgs,mats,m;
  p:=PrimePGroup(G);
  A:=AutomorphismGroup(G);
  phi:=FrattiniSubgroup(G);
  pcgs:=ModuloPcgs(G,phi);
  mats:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(A),hom->
    List(pcgs,a->ExponentsOfPcElement(pcgs,ImagesRepresentative(hom,a))));
  m:=Group(mats*One(GF(p)));
  return Size(m)=Size(GL(Length(pcgs),p));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Can I put this test inside a repetition to find all groups which have this property ? and which is better using command  "for .... do" or "Repeat" i want test small group for n=1.......100 and prime p= 3...7.

Comment: @Elias have you seen https://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups/ - you can use code from there with this `TestCondition` function. BTW, the library does not contain groups of order $p^n$ for all $n=1,...,100$ and prime $p= 3,...,7$.

Comment: Yes, i have already seen and thinking about this statement i dont know if  its usefull "                                           
              gap> for n in [1..360] do
              >      if not IsPrimePowerInt(n) then ".. i thought maybe there is another code to make iteraton.. thanks alot for your advice! Im new with GAP, so that i ask alot.

Comment: @Elias no problem, please ask! Of course you can adapt the code to iterate only over those orders which you need, etc.